# In MVC3 , getHtml giviing Column doesn't exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to populate the webgrid with the list of objects.
My HomeController is

```
namespace WebGridExample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly List<Student> list;
        public HomeController() {
            list = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student(){ID="111",Name="Tanu",Age="24"},
                new Student(){ID="122",Name="Danu",Age="20"},
                new Student(){ID="11",Name="Taniya",Age="18"},
                new Student(){ID="888",Name="Vidushi",Age="25"},
            };


        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(list.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

My Student Model is:

```
namespace WebGridExample.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name;
        public string ID;
        public string Age;

        public Student() { 

        }
        public Student(string Name,string ID,string Age) {

            this.Name = Name;
            this.Age = Age;
            this.ID = ID;
        }
    }
}
```

and my Index View is

```
@model List<WebGridExample.Models.Student>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<style type="text/css">
.webGrid{margin:4px;border-collapse:collapse;width:300px;}
.header{background-color:#E8E8E8;font-weight:bold;color:#FFF}
.alt{background-color: #E8E8E8;color:#000}
</style>
</head>
<body>
@{

    var grid = new WebGrid(source:Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);

}  
<p>Web Grid</p> 
<div id="webgrid">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: ".webGrid", headerStyle: ".header", alternatingRowStyle: ".alt", columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Name"), grid.Column("ID"), grid.Column("Age")));

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this I am getting an error at this line

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: ".webGrid", headerStyle: ".header", alternatingRowStyle: ".alt", columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Name"), grid.Column("ID"), grid.Column("Age")));
```

saying that Name column does not exist as well as if i give only @grid.getHtml() then, it doesnt not display anything. Please someone tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: see this http://pavanarya.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/displaying-data-in-a-grid-using-webgrid-in-cshtml/

Comment: Thanks Yasser. But unfortunately, I am getting blank screen when i run the app. Nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: update the code, if you are trying anything new, or are you still talking about the prev code ?

Answer (score 1):

Update your student model to and this should work fine

namespace WebGridExample.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name {set;get;}
        public string ID{set;get;}
        public string Age{set;get;}

```
    public Student() { 

    }
    public Student(string Name,string ID,string Age) {

        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,
pavan
[pavanarya.wordpress.com](http://pavanarya.wordpress.com)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

I modified the Student class to remove the constructors and define getters/setters and it worked fine:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```